# My Form detected as null when I submit and show my session error instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

This is the output of my program (trying to store data to database, I filled all the data)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCw06.png)

It refreshed the data at First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number

I suppose somehow the submit detects it as null and didn't work (show error session instead), since I  use this code to handle error

```
if (employeeInfo.FName == null || employeeInfo.LName == null ||
    employeeInfo.Position == null || employeeInfo.Status == null ||
    employeeInfo.DOB == null || employeeInfo.Sex == null ||
    employeeInfo.PNum == null || employeeInfo.Email == null ||
    employeeInfo.Address == null)
    {}
```

Any idea what am I missing ?

Here's I give my codes

```
public class CreateModel: PageModel 
{
  public EmployeeInfo employeeInfo = new EmployeeInfo();
  public String errorMessage = "";
  public String successMessage = "";

  public void OnGet() {

  }

  public void OnPost() {
    employeeInfo.FName = Request.Form["FName"];
    employeeInfo.LName = Request.Form["LName"];
    employeeInfo.Position = Request.Form["Position"];
    employeeInfo.Status = Request.Form["Status"];
    employeeInfo.DOB = Request.Form["DOB"];
    employeeInfo.Sex = Request.Form["Sex"];
    employeeInfo.PNum = Request.Form["PNum"];
    employeeInfo.Email = Request.Form["Email"];
    employeeInfo.Address = Request.Form["Address"];

    if (employeeInfo.FName == null || employeeInfo.LName == null ||
      employeeInfo.Position == null || employeeInfo.Status == null ||
      employeeInfo.DOB == null || employeeInfo.Sex == null ||
      employeeInfo.PNum == null || employeeInfo.Email == null ||
      employeeInfo.Address == null) {
      errorMessage = "All the field are required";
      return;
    }

    try {
      String connectionString = "Data Source=laptop-m04lrfr4\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Microservices;Integrated Security=True";
      using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        connection.Open();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Employee" + "(EmployeeId, FName, LName, Position, Status, DOB, Sex, PNum, Email, Address) VALUES" +
          "(@EmployeeId, @FName, @LName, @Position, @Status, @DOB, @Sex, @PNum, @Email, @Address);";

        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", employeeInfo.FName);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", employeeInfo.LName);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", employeeInfo.Position);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", employeeInfo.Status);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", employeeInfo.DOB);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", employeeInfo.Sex);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNum", employeeInfo.PNum);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", employeeInfo.Email);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", employeeInfo.Address);

          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      errorMessage = ex.Message;
      return;
    }
    // Add Data to Database
    employeeInfo.FName = "";
    employeeInfo.LName = "";
    employeeInfo.Position = "";
    employeeInfo.Status = "";
    employeeInfo.DOB = "";
    employeeInfo.Sex = "";
    employeeInfo.PNum = "";
    employeeInfo.Email = "";
    employeeInfo.Address = "";
    successMessage = "New Employee Added Successfully";

    Response.Redirect("/Employees/Index");
  }
 }
}
```

Model

```
@page
@model DataEmployee.Pages.Employees.CreateModel
@{
}

<br>
<hr2>Create Employee</hr2>

@if (Model.errorMessage.Length > 0)
{
    <div class="alert alert-primary fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>@Model.errorMessage</strong>
        Error!
    </div>
}

<form method="POST">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" value="@Model.employeeInfo.FName">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="lasttName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" value="@Model.employeeInfo.LName">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="position" class="form-label">Position</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="position" value="@Model.employeeInfo.Position">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="status" class="form-label">Status</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" value="@Model.employeeInfo.Status">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="dob" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" value="@Model.employeeInfo.DOB">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="sex" class="form-label">Sex</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sex" value="@Model.employeeInfo.Sex">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="@Model.employeeInfo.PNum">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="@Model.employeeInfo.Email">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="@Model.employeeInfo.Address">
    </div>

    @if (Model.successMessage.Length > 0)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-primary fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>@Model.successMessage</strong>
            Success!
        </div>
    }

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="/" role="button">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How exactly to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the model,you can try to use model validation,here is a n official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0),and here is a demo:

model:

```
public class EmployeeInfo
    {
        [Required]
        public string FName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LName { get; set; }
       ...


    }
```

cshtml(using `asp-for="employeeInfo.xxx"`,so that with `[BindProperty]` in cshtml.cs,the values of inputs will be binded to employeeInfo by default):

```
<div class="alert alert-primary fade show" role="alert">
    <strong id="content"></strong>
    Error!
</div>
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="employeeInfo.FName">
        <span asp-validation-for="employeeInfo.FName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
   

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="/" role="button">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script>
        $("#myForm").submit(function() {
            if (!$("#myForm").valid()) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "All the fields are required";
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public EmployeeInfo employeeInfo { get; set; } = new EmployeeInfo();
        public String errorMessage = "";
        public String successMessage = "";

        public void OnGet()
        {            

        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=laptop-m04lrfr4\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Microservices;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO Employee" + "(EmployeeId, FName, LName, Position, Status, DOB, Sex, PNum, Email, Address) VALUES" +
                        "(@EmployeeId, @FName, @LName, @Position, @Status, @DOB, @Sex, @PNum, @Email, @Address);";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {                        
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", employeeInfo.FName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", employeeInfo.LName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", employeeInfo.Position);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", employeeInfo.Status);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", employeeInfo.DOB);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", employeeInfo.Sex);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNum", employeeInfo.PNum);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", employeeInfo.Email);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", employeeInfo.Address);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
                return;
            }
            // Add Data to Database
            employeeInfo.FName = ""; employeeInfo.LName = ""; employeeInfo.Position = ""; employeeInfo.Status = ""; employeeInfo.DOB= ""; employeeInfo.Sex = ""; employeeInfo.PNum = ""; employeeInfo.Email = ""; employeeInfo.Address = "";
            successMessage = "New Employee Added Successfully";

            Response.Redirect("/Employees/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

result:
[image]

If you don't want to see the validation of inputs,you can remove `<span asp-validation-for="employeeInfo.FName" class="text-danger"></span>` in the code above.